# Quotes in Japanese about translation

Tags: discussion, support

Does anyone know how I could find quotes in Japanese about the labor of translation?

I'm interested in finding quotes in Japanese by Japanese writers or translators related with the difficulties of the job of translation.

I've tried to find them by searching on Google combinations of words like 翻訳, 名言 or 引用, but, surprisingly, it doesn't appear any site with quotes with the topic of 翻訳.

If you could help me to find these quotes or tell me how I should look for them, I'd appreciate it a lot.